# How do I prevent a pipe from flowing into a sub-shell in a script

Tags: shell, pipe

I'm piping lines into a PHP script (see contrived example below). Alas the pipe unintentionally flows into the shell command in the script, thus nano doesn't run because it chokes on STDIN.

I want the shell command to run completely unrelated to the STDIN piped to the main script. So the PHP script should in a way "eat" the STDIN, so it doesn't reach the sub-shell. How do I fix this?

Note that `exec()`, `system()` and `passthru()` all give the same result.

```
$ echo -e "World\nEverybody" | php script.php
Hello World
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
Hello Everybody
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

script.php:

```
<?php

foreach(file("php://stdin") as $name) {
  echo "Hello $name";
  passthru("nano");
}

?>
```

Environment:

- PHP 7.1.14 / PHP 5.6.30
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57

Comment: Why did you type the characters p,a,s,s,t,h,r and u in your script?

Comment: It's a PHP way of doing sub-shells. None of the supported methods work as expected.

Comment: @forthrin did you see that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11968244/1195001 They are not using the same code as you. I think your problem is more about php than pipe

Comment: @forthrin  True, but if you read the passthru manual page, what does it say about the output?

Comment: Well, yes processes inherit the file descriptors of their parent. What would you want its stdin to be?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Nothing :) The shell should run completely unrelated to the initial STDIN to the PHP script.

Comment: You mean `nano` should have its stdin closed? opened on /dev/null, on some tty device?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `nano` should simply run without receiving any STDIN, just like if you ran `nano` by itself on the command line. The STDIN is for the PHP script alone, not its sub-shells.

Comment: If you run nano directly on the command line in a terminal, of course it receives a stdin. Its stdin is the terminal device, something like `/dev/ttyX` or `/dev/pts/X`. If not you wouldn't be able to interact with it. In any case, looks like my answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, processes inherit the file descriptors of their parent, when you do:

In

```
php -r 'passthru("nano");'
```

`php` will inherit the stdin of the shell (a tty device if invoked at the prompt of an interactive shell) and `nano` will inherit it as well (while stdout is a pipe used by `php` to retrieve the output of `nano` and pass it through, `nano` seems to be happy with it, not all editors would, you may want to use `system()` instead here).

In:

```
something | php -r 'passthru("nano");'
```

You're calling `php` with it stdin now a pipe with `something`'s stdout at the other end. And `nano` will inherit it.

If you want `php`'s stdin to be the pipe, while `nano` stdin whatever the shell's stdin is, you'd need to somehow pass that resource to `php`, and have `php` (or the shell run by `passthru`) make it the stdin of `nano`. It could be done with for instance:

```
{ something 3<&- | php -r 'passthru("nano <&3 3<&-");'; } 3<&0
```

Where we make the resource on fd 0 (stdin) also available on fd 3 within a command group (`{...;}`), close it for `something`, which doesn't need it (`3<&-`), and tell the shell run by php's `passthru` to restore stdin from that fd 3.

Example:

```
$ php -r 'passthru("ls -l /proc/self/fd");'
total 0
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:12 0 -> /dev/pts/38
l-wx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:12 1 -> pipe:[22538485]
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:12 2 -> /dev/pts/38
```

fd 0 is a tty device for terminal interaction.

```
$ echo hello | php -r 'passthru("ls -l /proc/self/fd");'
total 0
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:12 0 -> pipe:[22539326]
l-wx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:12 1 -> pipe:[22530020]
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:12 2 -> /dev/pts/38
```

Now `ls`'s stdin is a pipe (the one `echo` is feeding).

```
$ { echo hello 3<&- | php -r 'passthru("ls -l /proc/\$PPID/fd /proc/self/fd <&3 3<&-");';} 3<&0
/proc/9202/fd:
total 0
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 0 -> pipe:[22544619]
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 1 -> /dev/pts/38
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 2 -> /dev/pts/38
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 3 -> /dev/pts/38
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 4 -> pipe:[22544623]

/proc/self/fd:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 0 -> /dev/pts/38
l-wx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 1 -> pipe:[22544623]
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Mar 19 15:17 2 -> /dev/pts/38
```

`ls`'s stdin has been made the tty  device again, while its parent (php) still has the pipe on stdin (see also the tty on fd 3 and another pipe on fd 4, probably the one it is reading the output of `ls` with).

So here, you need to change your php script to:

```
<?php
foreach(file("php://stdin") as $name) {
  echo "Hello $name";
  passthru("nano <&3 3<&-");
}
?>
```

And call it as:

```
{ printf '%s\n' World Everybody | php script.php; } 3<&0
```

To pass both resources (the pipe from `printf` and the original stdin) to `php`.

If you expect that `php` script to always be called from within a terminal and that `nano` should then always interact with the terminal (but then again, note that `php` makes its *stdout* **not** the terminal), you could change it instead to:

```
<?php
foreach(file("php://stdin") as $name) {
  echo "Hello $name";
  passthru("nano < /dev/tty");
}
?>
```

Where we hard-code `nano`'s stdin to be the controlling terminal.

Comment: `echo -e "World\nEverybody" 3<&-  | php script.php` and `passthru("nano <&3 3<&-");` gives `sh: 3: Bad file descriptor`. Maybe I'm getting you wrong. Could you provide a changed version of my script and command line that works?

Comment: @forthrin, you need to open that fd 3 to something (the original stdin) first with the `{ ...; } 3<&0`. See edit.

Comment: `nano < /dev/tty` works perfectly! I'll try to read up on the low level stuff on pipes. Perfect excuse to dig deeper into the magic realms of UNIX. Great explanation!